# How to resolve typeError for Kendo UI version 2015.3.1111

Tags: kendo-ui

I upgraded kendo ui version to 2015.3.111 and using jQuery 2.1.4. It shows:

```
TypeError: n.find is not a function
```

My included files are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/applicationplugin-0.1/theme/application/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/applicationplugin-0.1/theme/application/js/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```